# Pass variable to onClick Function

Tags: javascript, html, pug

Trying to open a picture in a new tab, the values comes from a looping object.
How will I pass the value of doc.strDocument to onClick ?

PUG:

```
a(onClick="window.open('/userImages/documents/'+doc.strDocument);")
```

HTML:

```
<a onClick="window.open('/userImages/documents/'+doc.strDocument);"></a>
```

Comment: Have you tried these?

Comment: What error or unwanted behaviour are you getting precisely?

Comment: Maybe you should show the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concatenation is fine (as long as `strDocument` has a value that when concatenated with the static text forms a valid URL).

But, this is much simpler when it comes to `<a>` elements - no `onclick` needed because `<a>` elements can target new windows with the `target` attribute.

```js
function getLink(){
  var someData = "foo";
  return "some/path/" + someData;
  console.log(link.href);
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:getLink()" target="_blank" id="testLink">test</a>
```

And, even that should be improved by moving the JavaScript out from being inline with the HTML:

```js
var someDynamicallyGottenValue = "foo";
var link = document.getElementById("dynamicLink");
link.href = 'http://someDomain.com/' + someDynamicallyGottenValue;
console.log(link.href);
```

```html
<a href="" target="_blank" id="dynamicLink">test</a>
```

Comment: Not sure about the `javascript:` scheme, since you're not calling any JavaScript.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yep. Didn't get much sleep last night - out shoveling. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass JSON data to Pug.

```
{"book": {"name": "Dracula"}}
```

And your PUG code would be,

```
a(onClick="window.open('/userImages/documents/#{book.name}');")
```

Pug also support variables.

```
- var foo = book.name;
a(onClick="window.open('/userImages/documents/#{foo}');")
```

Tested using - http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/#variables

Hope this helps.